# .Net Connector for SAP HANA with .Net Core

Tags: .net, hana, connector, sap-dotnet-connector

We are creating a web API for our organization. API connects and retrieves data from a HANA View. I am referring  the sample provided at the below link to establish the connectivity:

https://blogs.sap.com/2015/04/15/creating-a-c-application-using-sap-hana-and-adonet/

Since .Net Core does not allow DLL to be referenced directly, we are creating a local NuGet package and referencing the same (https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/creating-a-package)

I get the below error when I initialize HanaConection:

> {"Version mismatch:
> C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Sap.Data.Hana.v3.5\1.0.120.0__0326b8ea63db4bc4\Sap.Data.Hana.v3.5.dll
> (1.0.120.0), C:\Program Files\sap\hdbclient\libSQLDBCHDB.dll
> (1.00.112.00.1457615240).":"C:\Program
> Files\sap\hdbclient\libSQLDBCHDB.dll"}

Comment: SAP have added support for .net core from HANA 2.0 SPS4. See SAP Note 2499500 or here: https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.04/en-US/bd3548f9c00845849fe4d883148974d1.html

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your assembly expects a HANA rev. 120 driver, while a rev. 112 driver is actually installed.

Comment: I didn't understand...I have installed the latest available from SAP downloads.

Comment: @Chandan: Yea, that then means it requires an older version than the latest download...

Answer (score 1):

We had created the local nuget Package using x86 version of SAP .Net connector, our app was running on 64bit mode. Hence it was failing. I recreated the package using 64bit version of dll and the problem got resolved.

Comment: Could you explain it with more details. How could i pack old .DLL Files into an Nuget Package and is it always compatible? Thanks for your help

Comment: did you resolve this problem or do you still need help ?

Comment: I took the 64bit versions of the HANA assembly and recreated the nuget packages and then the issue got resolved

Comment: @Chandan are you sure you got this dll working under .Net Core (not normal .Net) as the title of your question suggests?

Comment: @Jpsy Yes it works - I know i am posting this too late.