# Connecting .NET Core web application to sap hana (could not load assembly)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-assembly, asp.net-core-2.2, linq2db

I am using linq2db as ORM for my web application project (ASP.NET Core 2.2) with SAP HANA database.

When I run my code including database queries I receive the following error (first 2 rows):

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Sap.Data.Hana, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
File name: 'Sap.Data.Hana, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I assumed that `Sap.Data.Hana` refers to the assembly SAP HANA provides in their data provider package. That's why I established a reference to the assembly `Sap.Data.Hana.v4.5.dll` using Visual Studio UI. However, I still receive the same error.

What could be the reason for this error? Am I using the wrong assembly file or do I have to establish the reference differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAP have added support for .net core from HANA 2.0 SPS4: [SAP HANA Client Interface Programming Reference for SAP HANA Platform](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.04/en-US/bd3548f9c00845849fe4d883148974d1.html)

Also see SAP Note 2499500.

Comment: Great! Finally they noticed .net core at least for HANA. We will add support in next linq2db version

Comment: It seems it works only on Windows: "The driver is Sap.Data.Hana.Core.v2.1.dll and it only runs on Microsoft Windows."

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you try to use SAP HANA provider from .net core application.
Unfortunatelly SAP doesn't have HANA provider for .net core, only for .net framework.

Comment: also check this question, maybe it will help somehow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498542/net-connector-for-sap-hana-with-net-core

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, that's correct. I try to use SAP HANA provider for .net core application.
Oh, I see. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to follow instructions in your linked question and create my own nuget package with the dll inside.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your Project to run on x64.